# How do I print floats as exponentials in gdb?

Tags: gdb

I want to print my variables in exponential form. Currently, I get:

```
(gdb) set $x=200.0500
(gdb) print $x
$3 = 200.05000000000001
```

I want:

```
  2.00E+002
```

or

```
  2.00E2
```

In other words, I want to control the digits printed also the exponential form.

Answer (score 2):

I did find an answer myself:

```
(gdb) python print "%0.2e" % (gdb.parse_and_eval('200.0000'))
2.00e+02
```

Comment: For Python3 extra parentheses are needed: `python print("%0.2e" % (gdb.parse_and_eval('200.0000')))`.

Comment: I am using python 2.7.x

Comment: I mean that the answer depends on python version gdb is linked with. Some gdb is linked with Python2, some with Python3. Mine is linked with Python3.

Comment: is there a pure gdb way? I need it for dprintf